# At which word does this "which" point?

Tags: relative-pronouns

> Such reactions may appear as edema or inflammation at the injection site or cause a variety of manifestations elsewhere, such as redness of the skin, itching, conjunctivitis, rhinitis, swelling of the face (angioedema), the upper or (and) lower lip, cheeks, vocal cords, pharynx accompanied by difficulty of breathing or swallowing, urticaria, severe dyspnea, **which** may progress to anaphylactic shock.

In the Russian original, the word "which" is in the plural (indicated by a plural ending), which makes it clear that it is "manifestations" that may progress to the shock.

However, in English it might seem like it points at "dyspnea" only, isn't it?

Is there a way in English to get around this ambiguity? "... , and these manifestations may progress to anaphylactic shock"? That's a bit unwieldy. To move "which may progress" directly to "elsewhere"?

Comment: I believe the antecedent is **swelling**, and that the parenthetic we talked about earlier should have included dyspnea.

Comment: @TRomano - thank you. It's interesting. Maybe it's better just to exile "which may progress to anaphylactic shock" into a separate sentence. "These manifestations may progress..."

Comment: But in such a messy list, we have to bring in extra-linguistic information to make that determination.

Comment: Actually, **reactions** would be a good candidate noun.  The symptoms (manifestations) don't progress to shock, the allergic reaction does.

Comment: "These reactions may progress to..". Nice, thank you!

Comment: Swelling can signal imminent danger.

Comment: The list in parentheses is a supplement, and as such it (or any part of it) cannot be the antecedent. This means that the antecedent can only be the noun **manifestations**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each of these manifestations "may progress to anaphylactic shock", then I believe it is possible to write

> [...] urticaria, severe dyspnea, **all of which** may progress to anaphylactic shock.

Although "all of which" does not directly refer to the word *manifestations* it should be clearer that each example can lead to anaphylactic shock. You can also consider "each of which" instead of "all of which".

Yes, the first time I read it, I thought it only referred to "dyspnea", not all of the examples.

If you want to refer to the word *manifestations* directly, then I would recommend simply starting a new sentence after the last example "dyspnea". Some possible sentences include

1. [...] urticaria, and severe dyspnea. Manifestations may progress to anaphylactic shock.
2. [...] urticaria, and severe dyspnea. These/Such manifestations may progress to anaphylactic shock.